# Conditional spread element

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ternary-operator

```
const cond = false

const extraInfo = [
  {
    a: 11,
    b: 25
  },
  {
    a: 12,
    b: 34
  },
  {
    a: 1,
    c: 99
  }
]

const userInfo = [
  {
    z: 8
  },
  {
    z: 10
  },
  ...(cond && extraInfo)
]
```

When `cond` is true, I want both extra and user info.

When `cond` is false, only userInfo is needed.

The issue is when `cond` is false, I get

> TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)[Symbol.iterator] is not a function

My understanding is that I am not allowed to use a boolean as a spread element, in this case `...false`.

But `...( cond ? extraInfo : {} )` doesn't seem to work either.

What is going on?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Just make it

```
...(cond ? extraInfo : [])
```

**Demo with true**

```js
var cond = true;

var extraInfo = [
  {
    a: 11,
    b: 25
  },
  {
    a: 12,
    b: 34
  },
  {
    a: 1,
    c: 99
  }
];

var userInfo = [
  {
    z: 8
  },
  {
    z: 10
  },
  ...(cond ? extraInfo : [])
];

console.log( userInfo );
```

**Demo with false**

```js
var cond = false;

var extraInfo = [
  {
    a: 11,
    b: 25
  },
  {
    a: 12,
    b: 34
  },
  {
    a: 1,
    c: 99
  }
];

var userInfo = [
  {
    z: 8
  },
  {
    z: 10
  },
  ...(cond ? extraInfo : [])
];

console.log( userInfo );
```

Comment: can change the conditional operator to `...(cond && extraInfo || [])`

Comment: Nice, but why!? If it accepts filled object why not empty one?

Comment: Now it makes sense! So objects are not iterable without the [Symbol.iterator] protocol that's why `...{}` wouldn't work?

Comment: @AswinRamesh That also works, thanks, I will add that as well.

Comment: @AswinRamesh No, don't do that. It's longer, more confusing, and works only if `extraInfo` is truthy.

Comment: @Liren It will work if both are object literals .. for example `var obj = {s:1};
var obj2 = { ...obj }`

Comment: @Akxe Sorry, I didn't get you.

Comment: @Akxe `extraInfo` is an array.

Answer (score 71):

Conditionally spread an entity to **Object**

```
console.log(
  { 
    name: 'Alex',
    age: 19,
    ...(true && { city: 'Kyiv' }),
    ...(false && { country: 'Ukraine' })
  }
) 

// { name: 'Alex', age: 19, city: 'Kyiv' }
```

Conditionally spread an entity to **Array**

```
console.log(
  [
    'Dan',
    'Alex',
    ...(true ? ['Robin'] : [])
  ]
)

// [ 'Dan', 'Alex', 'Robin' ]
```

Comment: So, what is the actual difference between spreading into object vs array? When trying to spread into array, one gets `Uncaught TypeError: boolean false is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))`.

Comment: I didn't know this can be done. Really concise in certain use cases. Nice!

Comment: @Qwerty, the problem here, with the object, that is causing the `TypeError`, is that an expression like `false && somethingElise` will always return `false`, that is not spreadable. You need to use ternary opeator here too, with an empty object if `false`, similar to the array example.

Comment: that doesn't work while in an array of objects

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

cond is true:

```js
var extraInfo = [
  {
    a: 11,
    b: 25
  },
  {
    a: 12,
    b: 34
  },
  {
    a: 1,
    c: 99
  }
]

var cond = true;
var userInfo = [
  {
    z: 8
  },
  {
    z: 10
  },
  ...(cond && extraInfo || [])
]
console.log(userInfo);
```

cond is false:

```js
var extraInfo = [
  {
    a: 11,
    b: 25
  },
  {
    a: 12,
    b: 34
  },
  {
    a: 1,
    c: 99
  }
]

var cond = false;
var userInfo = [
  {
    z: 8
  },
  {
    z: 10
  },
  ...(cond && extraInfo || [])
]
console.log(userInfo);
```

Comment: Why not use a proper ternary operator?

Comment: question of taste.

Comment: question of correctness, simplicity and performance. Of course you can have a horrible taste for them :-)

Comment: Are you sure ternary operator is more performant ? If you cannot understand it, that doesn't mean that it's horible

Comment: Yes it is, because it does not have to evaluate the truthiness of the value returned by the `cond && extraInfo` expression. It's one operation, not two. (Also: write what you mean)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const extraInfo = [
  {
    a: 11,
    b: 25
  },
  {
    a: 12,
    b: 34
  },
  {
    a: 1,
    c: 99
  }
];
const userInfo = [
  {
    z: 8
  },
  {
    z: 10
  },
];

const cond = true;
let getMyValue = cond ? [].concat(extraInfo, userInfo) : userInfo;

console.log(getMyValue)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let getMyValue = cond ? [].concat(extraInfo, userInfo) : userInfo;
```

let check this

```js
const extraInfo = [
  {
    a: 11,
    b: 25
  },
  {
    a: 12,
    b: 34
  },
  {
    a: 1,
    c: 99
  }
];
const userInfo = [
  {
    z: 8
  },
  {
    z: 10
  },
];

const cond = false;
let getMyValue = cond ? [].concat(extraInfo, userInfo) : userInfo;

console.log(getMyValue)
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Hi, I place my ans like bottom of the section , no issues let's check this